# Equinox shuts down after 30 seconds of inactivity

Tags: osgi, shutdown, equinox

I have an 'application' (not an eclipse application, hence the noShutdown and ignoreApp arguments below) that runs in an equinox osgi container. It is a sort of a server and if doesn't get any incoming message it shuts down after about 30 seconds. It's definitely not the socket's fault, I've already checked it. 
Also, if I start the app with the `-console` argument the framework doesn't shut down, but leaving it that way is not a good idea for production...
It's also strange that the phenomenon does not occur when I run the program from eclipse.
These are the standard args I use:

```
-consoleLog
-clean
-vmargs
-Declipse.ignoreApp=true
-Dosgi.noShutdown=true
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+UnsyncloadClass
```

What might cause this automatic shutdown despite the (I think) proper arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Watson's post on the eclipse forums the problem is now solved, I quote him:

> This looks to be bug 310426. What version of Equinox are you using. If it is earlier than 3.7 then try setting the following property:
>
> osgi.framework.activeThreadType=normal
>
> HTH
>
> Tom

Thanks again! (We've used 3.5.1)